# $\mathbb {Z}^2$ can be generated by the vectors $(w,x)$ and $(y,z)$, where $w,x,y,z \in \mathbb {Z}$, if $wz-xy= \pm1$ is satisfied.

Tags: group-theory

I'm struggling to prove that $\mathbb {Z}^2$ can be generated by the vectors $(w,x)$ and $(y,z)$, where $w,x,y,z \in \mathbb {Z}$, if $wz-xy= \pm1$ is satisfied.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $z(w,x)-x(y,z)=(\pm1,0)$ and $y(w,x)-w(y,z)=(0,\mp1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: That seems more like an answer than a comment to me?

Comment: Ok, @joriki, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: This is an entirely reasonable and significant question! Even if it's "easy", people need to know how to _do_ "easy" things! :)  Let's re-open, please.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb Z$ is generated by $\pm1$, so $\mathbb Z^2$ is generated by $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$.

Given the condition, we have $(\pm1,0)=z(w,x)-x(y,z)$ and $(0,\mp1)=y(w,x)=w(y,z),$

so $(w,x)$ and $(y,z)$ generate $\mathbb Z^2$.